# Cómo obtener datos Específicos de la respuesta de un api en Angular

Tags: typescript, angular12

Tengo definido una variable como any

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  caracteresMorty: any
```

y un método donde obtiene los personajes de RickAndMorty

```
getCharacterbyId(id: number) {
   this.service.getSingleCharacter(id).subscribe(
   resp => {
    this.caracteresMorty = resp;
    console.log(this.caracteresMorty);
  },
  err => {
   console.log(err);
 },
);
}
```

la respuesta es la siguiente indico el id=174

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al tratar de hacer un **map** o cualquier **.json** me dice que no existe la funcionalidad para Object

y lo que necesito es obtener los siguientes campos de ese response

**id**

**name**

**image**

**episode**

Como puedo realizar esto?

Answer (score 0):

> Tengo definido una variable como any

Eso significa que no sabes qué estás recibiendo. Es algo normal cuando estás explorando un API que no es tuya, pero conforme te familiarizas con dicha API, deberías evitar el uso de `any`. Viendo la respuesta HTTP que recibes, creo que podrías crear una interfaz tal que así:

```js
interface RickAndMortyCharacterLocation { name: string; url: string };
interface RickAndMortyCharacter {
  created: string;
  episode: string[];
  gender: string;
  id: number;
  image: string;
  location: RickAndMortyCharacterLocation;
  name: string;
  ... //resto de campos
}
```

Y de ese modo trabajar con un tipo conocido

```js
getCharacterbyId(id: number) {
  this.service.getSingleCharacter(id).subscribe(
  (resp : RickAndMortyCharacter) => {
    this.caracteresMorty = resp;
    // sabemos que la respuesta tiene ese campo
    console.log(resp.name);
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: hola creé la interface con los campos que necesito pero me sale el siguiente error: No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "(resp: RickAndMortyCharacter) => void" al parámetro de tipo "(value: Object) => void".
      Los tipos de parámetros 'resp' y 'value' no son compatibles.
        El tipo 'Object' se puede asignar a muy pocos tipos. ¿Se refería a usar el tipo 'any' en realidad? Uso Angular 13

Comment: Tienes que declarar que el método de tu servicio devuelve un `Observable<RickAndMortyCharacter>`

Answer (score 0):

Algo tarde, pero se podría realizar algo como lo que comparto a continuación. Usamos `catchError` de RxJS para manejar cualquier problema que pueda surgir, mientras que para obtener los valores que necesitas realizamos desestructuración.

**Servicio**

```
export class RickandmortyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  readonly apiUrl = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api';

  getCharacter(charId: number): Observable<Character> {
    return this.http.get<Character>(`${this.apiUrl}/character/${charId}`).pipe(
      map((resp) => {
        const { id, name, image, episode } = resp;
        return { id, name, image, episode };
      }),
      catchError(({ error }) => {
        return of(error.error);
      })
    );
  }
```

**Componente**

```
id = 174;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rickandmortyService.getCharacter(this.id).subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
    });
```

**Interface**

Comente lo que no necesitas para poder usar la interface para checar el tipado, pero esta es la respuesta del servidor.

```
export interface Character {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  // status: string;
  // species: string;
  // type: string;
  // gender: string;
  // origin: Location;
  // location: Location;
  image: string;
  episode: string[];
  // url: string;
  // created: Date;
}

export interface Location {
  name: string;
  url: string;
}
```

**Resultados**

Respuesta con el personaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Manejo de errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -2):

Tienes tres opciones, la primera es utilizar destructuring de parametros y que lo que te retorne es otro `Object` pero que contenga solo las propiedades que necesitas:

```js
const caracteresMorty = {
  id: 10,
  name: "Morty solitario",
  image: "jpg",
  episode: 666,
  xprop1: false,
  xprop2: 0,
  xprop3: ""
}

//Lo unico que debes verificar es que estas propiedades existan en el objeto.
//cuando colocas entre llaves las propiedades del objeto como parametro en una funcion,
//extraeras sus valores.

//si una variable tiene el nombre de la key de un objeto puedes omitir los (:)
//y el valor de la propiedad, de esta manera se le asignara a esa propiedad el
//valor de tu variable.
function filterObjectProperties({id, name, image, episode}){
  return {id, name, image, episode};
}

const newFiltered = filterObjectProperties(caracteresMorty);

console.log(newFiltered);
```

La segunda opcion es usar filter y map en conjunto y que te devuelva un array, aunque en este caso no se si sea recomendable... pues es mas facil identificarlo con una estructura de objeto.

```js
const caracteresMorty = {
  id: 10,
  name: "Morty solitario",
  image: "jpg",
  episode: 666,
  xprop1: false,
  xprop2: 0,
  xprop3: ""
}

//Object.entries devuelve un array por pares tal que:

/*
  ["name", "Morty solitario"],
  ["episode", 666]
*/

//Filtramos entonces los pares de valores que nos interesan y luego los retornamos.
//Recordemos que como es un array de arrays, siempre la primera pocision sera la key
//del objeto y la segunda el valor.
const newCharacters = Object.entries(caracteresMorty).filter(ch => {
  const key = ch[0];
  
  return key === "id" || key === "name" || key === "image" || key === "episode";
});

console.log(newCharacters);
```

Y por ultimo la tercera opcion y no se si recomendada seria hacer lo mismo que la segunda opcion pero esta vez convirtiendolo a un `Object`:

```js
const caracteresMorty = {
  id: 10,
  name: "Morty solitario",
  image: "jpg",
  episode: 666,
  xprop1: false,
  xprop2: 0,
  xprop3: ""
}

//No recomendaria hacer esto, ya que consume mucha cantidad de memoria y es absurdo
//Sin embargo igual está ésta otra opcion en la cual:

//Con object.keys obtenemos especificamente en un array solo las keys del objeto
//Algo como:

/*
  [id, image, episode, name, ...]
*/

//Luego al tener solo las keys que nos interesan, iteramos con un reduce
//Como segundo parametro del reduce le pasamos un objeto vacio
//Apartir de esto vamos llenando el objeto vacio con sus valores correspondientes
const newCharacters = Object.keys(caracteresMorty).filter(key => {
  return key === "id" || key === "name" || key === "image" || key === "episode";
}).reduce((curr, next) => {
  curr[next] = caracteresMorty[next];
  return curr;
}, {})

console.log(newCharacters);
```

**Nota**: Ten en cuenta que en todos los ejemplos he colocado unos datos de prueba llamados `caracteresMorty`, en tu codigo obviamente no es necesario tenerlo, ademas debes de tener en cuenta que en vez de usar en tu codigo:

```
caracteresMorty
```

deberas usar:

```
this.caracteresMorty
```

Comment: recuerda que utilizo Typescript y Angular 13 no javascript

Comment: No importa, angular también posee esos métodos como map y etc, solo debes importar rxjs para poder usarlo.

Comment: Posdata, como he dicho, se que se trata de angular, por eso hice el inciso al final de mi respuesta de que NO debes usar  `caracteresMorty` si no `this.caracteresMorty`, lo que pasa es que hice un ejemplo que pudiese correr en el snippet con javascript, pero eso mismo funcionaria en typescript, solo debes asegurarte de que ese objeto ya posea valores.

Comment: Sobre la versión de angular... He dejado varias alternativas, las dos últimas correrían bien, la primera quizás no por tu versión de angular